# How should Postgres be installed to run as a daemon under user name _postgres on Mac OSX?

Tags: django, postgresql, macos, homebrew, launch-daemon

I followed directions for installing Postgres on Mac OS X using Brew.  All worked well.  I placed a .plist in my `Library/LaunchAgents` and had Postgres running when I logged in.  However, when I logged out postgres shuts down (which is correct behavior for processes started by launchd which are in a user's `Library/LaunchAgents` directory).

I wanted to have the database running all the time for all users so I tried to move my file homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist into the directory `/Library/LaunchDaemons`.  I set the owner:group to root:wheel and set permissions as well.  This didn't work as Postgres said it wouldn't run as root (reported in the log file in `/usr/local/var/log`).  So I added a UserName and GroupName to be _postgres for each.  It wouldn't run, and I believe there were permission issues, which I gather is that postgres running as postgres running as user:group of _postgres:_postgres cannot read files in `/usr/local/var/postgres` or `/usr/local/var/log` which are all sholland:admin for user:group (brew installed files under my userid holland and group admin).  I changed the UserName to sholland and GroupName to admin in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`, and now postgres is running happily each restart as user sholland group admin.

This is all fine, but I would like to run Postgres under user _postgres instead. I imagine I could use `sudo chown _postgre:_postgres *` in /usr/local/var/log and /usr/local/var/postgres, but I don't know if there are other issues if I go that route.  It seems that it would all be cleaner if brew did the install with user:group _postgres:_postgres instead of under my username and group admin.

The motivation to be able to set user:group in homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist to _postgres:_postgres is that I will be migrating the project to a linux system on a server at my hospital where I will use Django to run a report generator and patient tracking system for my GI group.  I will need to run postgres under it's own user:group to keep permissions other than my personal userid in that environment.

So, how does one get brew to install postgres under user _postgres under Mac OS X?

Comment: Based on the motivation, consider running postgres within a linux container (docker). It will be beneficial in the long run.

Comment: As in https://www.docker.com/why-docker I think you mean.  That's quite interesting.  I appreciate the reference.  The guys in IT at the hospital are amused and surprised by their senior physician knowing something about IT.  I think I'll give credit to my stackoverflow.com friends.  I wouldn't even have thought to explore containerizing the services. I see it is a bit like virtualenv and python, just more generalized.